# Common Desktop Environment compile error OpenBSD PowerPC

Tags: compiler-errors, openbsd

I'm attempting to compile CDE for OpenBSD and am running to an error in atoi_pearson.C.

```
atoi_pearson.C: In member function 'int atoi_pearson::atoi(const char*, int, int, int) const':
atoi_pearson.C:144: error: 'struct reg_t' has no member named 'b1'
atoi_pearson.C:145: error: 'struct reg_t' has no member named 'b2'
atoi_pearson.C:148: error: 'struct reg_t' has no member named 'b3'
atoi_pearson.C:149: error: 'struct reg_t' has no member named 'b4'
atoi_pearson.C:153: error: 'struct reg_t' has no member named 'b1'
atoi_pearson.C:153: error: 'struct reg_t' has no member named 'b1'
atoi_pearson.C:154: error: 'struct reg_t' has no member named 'b2'
atoi_pearson.C:154: error: 'struct reg_t' has no member named 'b2'
atoi_pearson.C:156: error: 'struct reg_t' has no member named 'b3'
atoi_pearson.C:156: error: 'struct reg_t' has no member named 'b3'
atoi_pearson.C:157: error: 'struct reg_t' has no member named 'b4'
atoi_pearson.C:157: error: 'struct reg_t' has no member named 'b4'
*** Error 1 in programs/dtinfo/DtMmdb/utility (Makefile:970 'atoi_pearson.o')
*** Error 1 in programs/dtinfo/DtMmdb (Makefile:947 'all')
*** Error 1 in programs/dtinfo (Makefile:734 'all')
*** Error 1 in programs (Makefile:729 'all')
*** Error 1 in . (xmakefile:721 'all')
*** Error 1 in /root/cde/cde (Makefile:66 'World')
```

Any idea what to do?

Comment: There seems to be some effort to create a port for CDE, have you had a look at this https://github.com/jasperla/openbsd-wip/tree/master/x11/cde it's a bit old but may be a starting point.

Comment: I tried that and got an error saying xorg.cf wasn't found